# How can separate structure into different files using c

Tags: c

original struct shows blew

```
typedef struct {
        uint x;
        uint y;
    }RESERVE_TYPE;
extern RESERVE_TYPE myRam;
```

I need to separate into 2 header files

```
file1.h
typedef struct {
        uint x;
    }RESERVE_TYPE;
extern RESERVE_TYPE myRam;

file2.h 

typedef struct {
        uint y;
    }RESERVE_TYPE;
extern RESERVE_TYPE myRam;
```

---

after separated I want `len = sizeof(RESERVE_TYPE);` will be same result in main.c

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: @Karthikeyan RESERVE_TYPE will comflict error I'm try to solve this problem

Comment: Research [Include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

Answer (score 0):

You can separate them but if you include them in main.c you'll get an error at compile time because you've used the same name in both header files. Depending on what you want to achieve, using a union will be more accurate. Something like

```
typedef union{uint x; uint y} RESERVE_TYPE;
extern RESERVE_TYPE myRam;
```

Comment: yep , but the problem still exist , we can't separate them